# Using two(multi) dimensional array in Erlang

Tags: arrays, erlang

These days I'm solving [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems in Erlang.

Since I'm a C++ programmer from the beginning, sometimes I really want to code using two dimensional arrays.

One of my idea is to use tuples and lists like this:

```
List=[{X,0}||X<-lists:seq(1,3)]
{1,0}
{2,0}
{3,0}
```

Is there nice way to implement multidimensional arrays in Erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [array module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) but for multidimensional access you have to write your own wrapper. If any of your dimension is short and access is mostly read you can use tuples and use `erlang:element` and `erlang:setelement`. Own wrapper is recommended anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try array(actually dict) with {X, Y, Z} as a key. It's look like 3d array ;)

Comment: is there an easy way to initialise it with an initialiser list?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small wrapper over array module for 2d arrays

```
-module(array_2d).
-export([new/2, get/3, set/4]).

new(Rows, Cols)->
    A = array:new(Rows),
    array:map(fun(_X, _T) -> array:new(Cols) end, A).

get(RowI, ColI, A) ->
    Row = array:get(RowI, A),
    array:get(ColI, Row).

set(RowI, ColI, Ele, A) ->
    Row = array:get(RowI, A),
    Row2 = array:set(ColI, Ele, Row),
    array:set(RowI, Row2, A).
```